# CSS link background-color on hover

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

I've got this code

```
<nav><details><summary>Pests</summary><ul>
    <li><a href="somewhere">Bugs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Rodents</a></li></ul>
</details></nav>
```

with this css

```
nav > details li:hover{background-color:white}
details > ul{list-style:none;background-color:orange;padding-left:15px;margin:0 15px}
```

When I hover over the link there's a small section of orange background that remains. How do I change the code so that the entire line background turns white? I've tried variations of taking out the padding etc. but that changes the space formatting in unwanted ways. Little help. Thanks.

Comment: you might need to include an image for the audience to have a better idea of what the problem is.

Comment: `UL` has orange background and 15px left padding. On hover you color only the `A` elements backgrounds in white - and yet you're asking why there's 15px orange?!

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
   nav > details li{padding-left: 15px;}
   nav > details li:hover{background-color:white;}
   details > ul{list-style:none;background-color:orange;padding-left:0;margin:0 15px}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove default `user agent styles` from your UL element.
**Instead, style your `A` elements:**

```css
nav > details > ul {
  background: orange;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;    /* you don't need that user agent styles margin. Null it */
  padding: 0;   /* you don't need that user agent styles padding. Null it */
}

/* instead style your a elements */

nav > details li a {  
  display: block;      /* make it block-level */
  padding: 5px 15px; 
  transition: 0.3s;    /* smooth transition */
}

nav > details li a:hover {
  background: white
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <details>
    <summary>Pests</summary>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="somewhere">Got Bees?</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Wasps, Hornets &amp; Yellow Jackets</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Got it?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</nav>
```

Comment: While in principle what you are suggesting works, many popular libraries use left padding to ensure content looks good on all devices and then apply left negative margins to items that shouldn't be padded. If this was such a bad idea, Bootstrap wouldn't have been so popular today. This technique is the bread and butter of Bootstrap's alignment of rows, cells and often menu items. Your solution will potentially affect the display of other children of the same container, as you're only seeing an [mcve].